# Looking for php files in two places and overriding the file if exists in the main directory

Tags: php, html, apache, smarty

I would like to have some base files to be used across two sites, and then have them override the base file if there is a file found in lets call it the parent/main directory. Otherwise look in the secondary base directory.

I am developing a site that is pretty much a duplication, but there are only a few files that would be different. So in order to save me copying and pasting the whole site a feature like this would be very useful.

Has anybody come across a similar type of requirement, any information would be help.

I am also using Smarty Templating here.

Thanks

Comment: so you want two versions of the same project, basically, but the only difference between them is the include-path and how the autoloader is going to use that path? (hint, the answer is implied by this question)

Comment: Wouldn't this be for just the classes themselves. As my classes are already being auto loaded across all sites.

Comment: Not really, since your autoloader will also check the include paths, the behaviour of the `include` and `require` language constructs is affected, too. functions like `file_exists` don't use the include paths, though. It's like a *NIX system. if your `shutdown` command is in `/sbin`, and your `$PATH` environment variable doesn't `sbin`, typing `shutdown -h 0` will result in an unknown command error. first typing `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin` will fix this, because the environment variable `$PATH` can be used to locate the actual command. Same logic applies to the include path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kohana Framework uses this type of structure. You've got 3-level directories:

- application
- modules
- system

Kohana firstly searches for files in application folder, then in modules and in the end in system folder. Browse their code to see their solution for this problem.

The simple answer is to create own [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) method, for example:

```
MAIN_DIR = '/my_base_dir';
ADDITIONAL_DIR = '/my_additional_dir';

function __autoload($class_name) {
     if (file_exists(MAIN_DIR . $class_name . '.php') {
         include MAIN_DIR . $class_name . '.php';
     } elseif (file_exists(ADDITIONAL_DIR . $class_name . '.php') {
         include ADDITIONAL_DIR . $class_name . '.php');
     } else {
         throw new Exception('Class ' . $class_name . ' not found!');
     }
}
```

And use it for loading PHP files.

Comment: Thanks i will look into this, however is this not intended for classes only? As i would like to load the PHP files like an index.php that calls the smarty .tpl files.

Comment: Autoloading is generally intended for classes, but Smarty has his own autoloader, which you can extend. In `smarty_parser.php` you have file-looking function (`parse();`) which you can change to look for more than one location.

Comment: This has been very helpful thank you. For Smarty i used `$smarty->setTemplateDir(array())` to setup multiple template locations to look at. If only it was as simple as this for PHP files. Thanks again